# JS pass result from function to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function oneFunc(elemDiv) {
  $('div.test').each(function() {
    elemDiv = $(this).text();
  });
  return elemDiv;
}

function twoFunc() {
  var fromOneFunc = oneFunc(); // I need to get 1,2,3 to here. But resalt is only last element - (3).
  $('span.get_text').each(function() {
    $(this).text(fromOneFunc); // I am trying for everyone to assign value of ** span ** from ** div **. But its do not work.
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="test"> 1 </div>
<div class="test"> 2 </div>
<div class="test"> 3 </div>

<span class="get_test"> 1 </span>
<span class="get_test"> 2 </span>
<span class="get_test"> 3 </span>
```

I need to get value of each element of DIV and pass to **twoFunc**.
But in twoFunc output of result only last of element of value (3).
I ask to help understand that my mistake.
Thank you in advance for all who are not indifferent.

Comment: Everyone is trying to fix your code but i would recommend reading a bit more documentation. There are a lot of misunderstandings in your snippet.

Comment: Thank you for ansver. I will read more rules about JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add each of the results to an array:

```
function oneFunc(){
  var elems = [];
  $('div.test').each(function(){    
     elems.push($(this).text()); 
  });
  return elems;
}

function twoFunc(){
  var fromOneFunc = oneFunc(); // I need to get 1,2,3 to here. But resalt is only last element - (3).
  $('span.get_text').each(function(a, i){
    $(this).text(fromOneFunc[i]); // I am trying for everyone to assign value of ** span ** from ** div **. But its do not work.
  })
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question please select it as the correct answer